# Insert text before the last line betweeen two matches in sed or awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I'm having file like this:

```
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
    }
```

this can repeat just with different "types"

I would like t insert something right before  the last } in the "set"

So it would look like ( not sure if awk or sed can somehow detect how many spaces have the line before :D ):

```
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
        something
    }
```

I can match it with

```
sed "/type.*.car.*/,/\} .... something here..."
```

file I just can't figure it out.. I cant look for "wheels" as that can be something different. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add something only when "type"="car" or for any type?

Comment: based on given input and what you've tried with `sed`, this might work.. `sed -e '/type.*car/,/}/ { /}/i\        something' -e '}' file` (add spaces as required after ``i\``) .. if not, then do add more details

Comment: @Toto just for specific type, not for every type

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<type\>.*\<car\>/{h;:a;n;/^\s*}/!ba;x;s/\S.*/something/;G}' file
```

Look for a line containing the required `type`, copy that line and then read/print subsequent lines until one that begins with a right curly brace. Swap back to the copied line and replace everything from the first non-space with the required string, append the line containing the right curly brace and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
    }
    set {
        type "second"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
    }
```

If you want to add "something" only when`type "car", run this:

```
perl -0777 -ape 's/set\h*{[^}]*type "car"[^}]*\K(?=\n\h+})/\n\tsomething/g' file.txt 
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
        something
    }
    set {
        type "second"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
    }
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/          # substitute
  set           # literally
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  {             # opening curly brace
  [^}]*         # 0 or more non curly brace
  type "car"    # literally
  [^}]*         # 0 or more non curly brace
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  (?=\n\h+})    # positive lookahead, make  sure we have after a linefeed and some horizontal spaces and a closing curly brace
/           # with
  \n            # linefeed
  \t            # a tab
  something     # whatever you want
/g          # end subs, global
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk` script (standard Linux gawk).

#### script.awk

```
/ +set {/,/ +}/{
    if($0 ~ /type "car"/ ) f = 1; 
    if($0 ~ / +}/ && f == 1) {
        print "        something";
        f = 0;
    }
}1
```

#### input.txt

```
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
    }
    set {
        type "baot"
        product "nice"
        dealer "here"
        features "1"
        wheels 0
    }
    set {
        type "horse"
        product "too"
        dealer "very"
        features "2"
        wheels 0
    }
}
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

#### output:

```
subset {
    set {
        type "car"
        product "ww"
        dealer "something"
        features "0"
        wheels 4
        something
    }
    set {
        type "baot"
        product "nice"
        dealer "here"
        features "1"
        wheels 0
    }
    set {
        type "horse"
        product "too"
        dealer "very"
        features "2"
        wheels 0
    }
}
```

Comment: They want to add something only when type=car.